# Replace `any` in generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I have type

```
interface Action<T = any> {
    type: T
}
```

which I cannot change as it's defined in an external library (Redux).

Then I have type defined as follows (in reality it is union type, but it doesn't matter)

```
type Pattern<A extends Action> = A["type"]
```

And `function`

```
function f1<A extends Action>(pattern: Pattern<A>, worker: (action: A) => any)
```

If I invoke `f1` for `Action` that has type argument `T` set to something more specific than `any`, everything is fine. I have `pattern` argument to have some specific type.

```
f1('pattern', (action: Action<string>) => {})
```

But if `Action` will be with default type for `T`, `pattern` will have type `any`. I want to avoid this, as this is incorrect. If `T = any` I want `pattern` to be `string` but not `any`.

I have tried to play with generics, but with no luck. Constructs like this

```
type Pattern<A extends Action> = any extends A["type"] ? string : A["type"]
```

not produce desired results. For say `Pattern<Action<number>>` result will be `string | number`. (I understand that it happens because `any` means that TS knows nothing about type). But question how to achieve desired result.

I can change `Pattern` and `f1`, but not `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

You've said you can change `Pattern` and `f1`, so one solution is to change `Pattern` to have a default `Action<string>` for `A`:

```
type Pattern<A extends Action = Action<string>> = A["type"];
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then define `f1` with just `Pattern`, not `Pattern<Action>`:

```
function f1(patt: Pattern): void {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
    patt; // type is any
}
```

you can still use `Pattern<Action<number>>` or whatever where appropriate when you want something other than `Action<string>`:

```
function f2(patt: Pattern<Action<number>>): void {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    patt; // type is number
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iAPAFWQF5k4QBPAPmQG8AoZR5McgBwgC5l86BfOui3bIACnDCQoeVMggAPSCAAmAZzQZsIYusw5cKsFFABzStRKoA2gCIhEawF0A3AJgBXEBpzIYARgAUrOJgXGIS0CAAlFwAbljASrQMTEESTsgA9BnMbCjAamTkfK4eXlowAEyBwaHBEbjounggbgC2AEbQZtHIcQlJTMipYOlZOcL5yC0d0HxAA)